# How to load R Kernel Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, r, jupyter

I am trying to load the R kernel into Juypter Notebook. I have the Ubuntu op sys. 16.04.3 LTS.  I am using the instructions from [here](https://marcocarnini.github.io/software/2016/08/01/installing-r-kernel-for-jupyter.html). Everything seems to fine until I try to run the following code: `devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')`. At this point it tells me that there is no package called devtools. I just want to get the R kernel going without it taking me all night long.

Comment: Did you try `install.packages("devtools")`?

Comment: @N0rbert: yes, after they install the terminal says 'The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpbJrbMH/downloaded_packages’
)'  Do I need to somehow access them from this location?

Comment: I get IRkernel installed after installation of devtools package. For package compilation you need to install `build-essential` package with `apt`.